# LogLevel overriding for Azure function via App setting not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function app that I am trying override the logging with.  I had a similar issue locally which is resolved locally due to a clean and a rebuild as VS2022 was not taking reading the local.settings.json file even though it was newer.

As we can see in the image (left is the azure monitoring which is set to verbose and showing the debug message. Right is it running in the console and the debug message is not there. Please excuse the heavy and crude redaction.

[image]

The next image is the local.settings.json and host.json file with Information being set as the logging level on part of our namesapce also redacted.

[image]

If I set this to local.settings.json to debug I get the debug logging out with line

`"AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__xx.yy.zz.": "Debug",`

Additionally if I set it to warning, I still get all the Information Logs

[image]

When I deploy this to Azure and its in the Azure Function App I have the same app setting

[image]

However, the problem that I am having is no matter what I set the value to I do not get the debug logs out in Azure Function Monitoring \ Invocations Logs.

[image]

The namespace as mentioned is xx.yy.zz. and this was a fix to prevent logs from filling up the file system within seconds and causing the function to fail so needs to stay this way.

However, the question is what am I doing wrong in Azure that this is not working and logging the correct Debug information when setting to debug?

Comment: When running on Azure, why not update the host.json file to Debug for your namespace?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran the company want to have a default level of verbose \ debug in dev, qa and staging and then pre-prod and prod have it as information with the ability to change it on the fly without having to redeploy the app service. 

We deploy using bicep files and github actions, so this needs to be configurable

Comment: There is a related issue still open, as I said earlier, you should create issue in github repo. I think if ILogger is injected the only log level determination is by the host.json file. So your need cannot be met as is. See https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2069

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran locally is working fine now, although it does need a clean and a rebuild each time

Comment: See the note in this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring#configure-categories), if you get a typed ILogger it won't behave as normal ILogger. How are you getting the logger , and are you running in-proc or out of proc.

Comment: were using ILogger<T> and is in proc. looking at the issue reported Im going to have to make some code changes

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran looking at the link you sent and this link too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection what I want to do, and the way I want to do things are not compatible...  Thanks for your help